# Bash Script to create another file

Tags: bash

I created a simple shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
echo "Starting Script now....."
echo "Write the info below to a new file in same directory...."

echo "name: John Smith"
echo "email: jsmith@demo.com
echo "gender: M"
echo 
echo
echo "File is done"
```

I want to create a file in the same directory with the Name, email, and gender details.
I don't want to do it from the command line like this:

```
#./script.sh > my.config
```

I'd rather do it from within the file itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, just add >> yourfile to the echo lines you want to write :

```
echo "name: John Smith" >> yourfile
echo "email: jsmith@demo.com" >> yourfile
echo "gender: M" >> yourfile
```

Answer (score 15):

Heredoc.

```
cat > somefile << EOF
name: ...
 ...
EOF
```

Answer (score 4):

You can just do:

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
echo "Starting Script now....."
echo "Write the info below to a new file in same directory...."

# save stdout to fd 3; redirect fd 1 to my.config
exec 3>&1 >my.config

echo "name: John Smith"
echo "email: jsmith@demo.com"
echo "gender: M"
echo 
echo

# restore original stdout to fd 1
exec >&3-

echo "File is done"
```

Answer (score 0):

For all your `echo "name:John Smith"` lines add a `> $1` (ie first parameter passed in to the script).

Then run the script like `./script.sh my.config`.

Or you could replace the `$1` with `my.config` and just run `./script.sh`.